# SQL Alchemy + Postgres + Python Integrity Error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have got an python application which runs on version 2.7 using postgres 9.1 with sqlalchemy 0.7 i believe.

I have a wx python gui from which i add and delete items.The code was working fine but now after making some modifications i recieve

```
$self.session.commit()
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 645, in commit
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 313, in commit
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 297, in _prepare_impl
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1547, in flush
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1616, in _flush
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 328, in execute
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 472, in execute
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 2291, in _save_obj
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1405, in execute
$ File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1538, in           
$ _execute_clauseelement
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1646, in     
$_execute_context
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1639, in 
$_execute_context
$  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 330, in do_execute
$sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates
$ unique constraint "Equipment_pkey"
$DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) already exists.
$ 'INSERT INTO "Equipment" (name, "numPorts") VALUES (%(name)s, %(numPorts)s)     
$RETURNING "HWCIs".id' {'numPorts': 0, 'name': u'jkhj'}
```

Now when i restart the application the key id increases by one.I can clearly see that something is resetting the id sequence of the database. Could anypne please help on how i can fix this issue by writing python code or what is the easiet step to overcome this issue . I tried working through psql commands but i was unsuccessful due to my lack of knowledge.If solution can explained in easy steps that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the answer. I was conencting to another database connection which caused the database sequence to reset to 1. So when application starts it seeks to `position 1`. So I just needed to change the `sequence` to `last no`. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

There is everything in the logs:

You are inserting a row with id=4 but there is already row with this id.

Do you have the row with id=4 in the table?